# Switch (True); The same column contain multiple search criteria in Power BI

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, powerbi, dax

1. If column A contain "TP" then "Yes".
2. If column A contain "TP-" then "Yes".
3. If column A contain "-A" then "Yes".
4. If column A does not contain "TP","TP-","-A" then desired result is "No".

In Excel I am applying the following formula in order to get the my final result.

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"*TP","*TP-*","*-A*"})),"YES","NO")
```

**Note:**

Column A contain text and numbers and Prefix and suffix or prefix with suffix as well.

DATA and DESIRED RESULT;

```
ITEM        DESIRED RESULT
1234567TP           YES
1234567TP-0001      YES
1234567TP-0001DR    YES
1234567TP-DR0001DR  YES
1234567TP-A0006DR   YES
1234567TP-A90001DR  YES
1234567TP-A0001DR   YES
7674859YO-A891      YES
456YO-A12           YES
87654HI-A0000098    YES
1234678VU           NO
1234678VU-P00094    NO
1234678VU-P00089    NO
1234678VU-P00567    NO
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this DAX formula to obtain the expected result:

```
Desired Column = 
IF( 
    CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[ITEM], "TP" ), "YES", 
    IF( 
        CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[ITEM], "TP-" ), "YES",
        IF( 
            CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[ITEM], "-A" ), "YES",  "NO"
        )
    )
)
```

Just to mention, the "TP-" condition is not needed because you  have the "TP" condition. I just added to keep your logic.

Comment: Thnak you so much for your help and advise. Your solution working well.

Answer (score 1):

Either use IF with the OR operator ||

```
NewColumn2 = 
    IF(
        CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Item],"tp") || CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Item],"-a"), "Yes",
            "No"
    )
```

or if you have many possible outcomes, switch can be cleaner

```
NewColumn = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Item],"tp"), "Yes",
    CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Item],"-a"), "Yes",
    "No"
    )
```